# How to handle static file while hosting website on heroku and mlab

Tags: mongodb, heroku, mern

I am making a MERN app and I am thinking of hosting it on `Heroku` and for database, I am using `mlab` But here I am confused about how and where can I handle static files. Like in my app user will upload a picture where should I put them. As mlab or MongoDB is going hold only path URLs if I am not wrong.

Hope this question makes sense, I am confused about it.
please help me figure this out

Comment: What is your maximum image size?

Comment: @Mani upto 3 MB

Comment: @Chris not really I know about Amazon aws but I want to use any free platform for storing my data.

Comment: @adityakumar, then your question is off-topic. We're not here to find or recommend off-site resources. See [help/on-topic]. We _can_ tell you that you can't permanently store your files on Heroku's filesystem.

Comment: @Chris this is what i want to know i thought i can store files on heroku. Thank you.

Comment: The duplicate I recommended says as much.